# not able to run rest api in java

Tags: java, rest, jersey, tomcat8

I have created dynamic web project and added all jaxrs-ri jar files to lib folder.The image added will show my project structure. I have configured tomcat 8.0 on my system and properly configured it. These are the files.

**LoginPage.java**

```java
package com.login;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/loginpage")
public class LoginPage {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello World RESTful Jersey!";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello World RESTful Jersey"
                + "</hello>";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello World RESTful Jersey"
                + "</title>" + "<body><h1>" + "Hello World RESTful Jersey"
                + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>LoginForm</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTful Jersey Hello World Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.javapapers.webservices.rest.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTful Jersey Hello World Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Console Message**

[image]

**Project Structure**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
<param-value>com.javapapers.webservices.rest.jersey</param-value>
```

should read

```
<param-value>com.login</param-value>
```

which is where you have your root resource...

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare the package name of controller class in servlet.xml like

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dibyendu.controller"></context:component- 
scan> and use @Controller or @RestController in the LoginPage class so that it can be 
considered as Controller.
```